# C—segfault when modifying data

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

Relating to an earlier question I had about displaying the contents of specific data addresses, I'm now trying to modify the contents of individual addresses. It seems like a simple enough task, but I get a segfault every time I try. I'm using the following function:

```
int mem_set(Cmd *cp, char *arguments)
{
    int address = 0, value = 0;
    char *location;

    if(sscanf(arguments, "%x %x", &address, &value) == 2)
    {
        location = (char*)address;
        *location = value;
    }
    else printf("Invalid input.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm supposed to be able to change an item in a table (in this very file) from 's' to 'x' by finding its address and replacing it with the proper hex value, but I get a segfault when it gets to `*location = value;`. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused: what exactly are you trying to change?  Are you trying to change the contents of your program's memory?  Are you trying to change the contents of a table in memory?  Are you trying to change the contents of a file?

Comment: I'm trying to change the contents in a .c file, specifically a command table, so that 'x' will call an exit function, whose command is currently 's.'

Comment: When you say "contents in a `.c` file", do you mean that you want to change part of your program which is running (because by the time it's running, it's no longer part of the .c file)?

Comment: Supposedly, I can use this command to change the program while it's running. The exact wording of the question is "Change the stop command from 's' to 'x' while the tutor program is running." Tutor is the name of the program I'm running, and the stop command is in a file called cmds.c, which the program is dependent on. Sorry if this doesn't help too much, my most recent (and first ever) C course was two semesters ago.

Comment: Bad news: you're on the wrong path for solving that problem.  Horribly wrong.  Rather than modifying the program at runtime (which is far, far beyond your skill level... and should almost never even be done in the first place... and is not even possible on some platforms), try altering the program so that the key for the stop command is stored in a variable, and then you can modify the variable at runtime (instead of modifying the *program* at runtime).  Short answer: You're solving a very easy problem in the most difficult way imaginable.

Comment: To be honest, it sounded like replacing a bolt in a wheel on a vehicle while it's moving. I'm not trying to relive Speed but with C instead of a bomb on a bus. I'm supposed to be changing the command specifically with this method, or something similar to it—find the byte where a command is stored, and edit it directly. If it were stored in a variable, would I still be able to use a method like this to change it? I know it's incredibly roundabout, but this is what my professor has asked me to do...

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this approach.  One problem is that on most modern systems, the program will be mapped read-only.  Another problem is that it's difficult to figure out which address to change, and which value the address should be changed to.  There are just too many unknowns here.  You should probably (in order of preference) post a question to your class mailing list or forum, or ask the TA, or drop by your professor's office hours.  They will know the specifics of the problem, but we don't know enough to help you.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an integer to a pointer here

```
location = (char*)address;
```

it should be

```
location = (char*)&address;
```

you need to take the address of `address` isntead  of it's value.

Whether this will do what you are trying to do, is something else, but this is the reason your program is invoking undefined behavior, which might lead to a SEGMENTATION FAULT.

Comment: It got rid of the segfault, but I don't think it's doing what I need it to do now. I have another function called mem_display that uses the same line `location = (char*)address;` to find the bits at that address. So far, that's been working well—I've been able to find bits of string literals and stuff in my code with it.

I just want to, say, change a random character in one of those string literals to an X, or something like that.

Comment: You can't change string literals, it's undefined behavior.